# Kafka producer request.timeout.ms does not appear to be working

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I have a Kafka producer with a 250 ms `request.timeout.ms`. All other configs are set to their default.

```
        var producerConfig = new ProducerConfig
        {
            Acks = Acks.All,
            RequestTimeoutMs = requestTimeoutMs
        };
```

I also have the following code:

```
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        await _KafkaProducer.ProduceAsync(kafkaTopic, kafkaMessage, cancellationToken);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        LogProduceLatency(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

My understanding is that with my configs, if the `ProduceAsync` call takes more than 250 ms, it should timeout and retry. This should continue for `delivery.timeout.ms` (which, for me, is set to the default of 2 minutes). Instead, I see instances of `ProduceAsync` calls taking up to 900 ms.

Am I misunderstanding something here or is something else likely configured incorrectly? It seems to me that with my `request.timeout.ms` setting, I should never see a `ProduceAsync` call that takes more than 250 ms.